# Explanation asked about the value of 'this' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I have this class in Javascript:

```
return function (settings) {
    var items = [],
        formHelper = new FormHelper(items),
        that = this;

    this.currentItem;

    this.initialize = function () {
        settings.listFn().then(function (response) {
            angular.copy(response, items);

            if (response.length > 0) {
                that.setCurrentItem(response[0]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the `initialize` method, I use a promise. When this promised is finished, the anonymous function is executed. Within the function you see the use of `that`, which is declared at line 4. When I use the `this` keyword instead of `that`, `this` points to `window`, while `that` points to the object.

I am wondering why this is. Could someone explain how this works? Why it behaves like this?

Comment: It's explained extensively in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: also have a look at [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: `this` depends on how the function gets called. `.then` is not aware of your class, that's why you need to keep a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by how the function is **called**, not by how or where it is **defined**.

Since you are passing the function to some third party code (`.then`), you have to be aware that it is not *you* who calls the function, but the third party code, and you won't have any control over *how* the function is called.
At some point the callback will most likely be called in the way that most functions are called, simply as

```
someFunction()
```

In that case, `this` refers to the *global object* which happens to be `window` in browsers (`this` is `undefined` if the function is in strict mode).

[More information on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

The callback you pass to the promise gets called asynchronously. In that case, `this` refers to the default context, which is the global `window` in the browser, and `module` in node.js, for example.

If you want to prevent this, use `.bind()` to set the context of the function to your liking. *(Note: Without polyfill, `.bind()` is not available until IE9)*

```
this.initialize = function () {
    settings.listFn().then(function (response) {
        angular.copy(response, items);

        if (response.length > 0) {
            that.setCurrentItem(response[0]);
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: *"[...]  gets called asynchronously. In that case, `this` refers to the default context, [...]"* The fact that `this` refers to `window` has nothing to do with the function being called asynchronously. You make it sound like it does.

Comment: Does `this` in an asynchronous call always refers to the `window`?

Comment: @FelixKling What is the fact why `this` refers to `window`?

Comment: @Martijn: Because the function will (most likely!) be called "normally", like `func();`. And in that case, `this` always refers to `window` (and `undefined` in strict mode). See the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call.

Comment: @FelixKling But the function is called within my class, ain't that strange behavior?

Comment: @Martijn: No, the function is not called in your class. It is called by `.then`. You are only defining a function and pass it to another function so that that function can call it. And as you hopefully have already read in the MDN documentation, the value of `this` is determined by how the function is **called** not by how or where it is **defined**.

Comment: @FelixKling, I think it's very confusing, but thanks. Could you create an answer so I can accept it? (and yes, I just read it :))